# How does the power switch of an active noise canceling headphone work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, switches, guitar-pedal

I have a noise cancelling headphone that still works as a passive headphone when turned off, even with the battery removed. How does this work?

In my mind noise cancelling is basically adding negative noise to the signal, so I suppose it is something like an adder.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4SNvB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, when it is turned off, it appears to still work as though the whole adder is not even there. It seems unlikely that it drives the output through R2 and R3, as it would attenuate the signal.

I'm trying to replicate this behaviour for a guitar pedal that adds extra stuff when turned on, but passes on the input when turned off.

Comment: Are you sure it has only one set of speakers? i.e., is there a separate speaker for the cancellation?

Comment: Your circuit (with an opamp) is not what is used as the opamp needs power. As the headphones still works without batteries, there's obviously no opamp in the signal path.

Comment: In the last one I took apart, there were pchannel MOSFETs for the through signal. How yours works, you have to take our apart. It might even be built into a physical switch

Comment: @Transistor having owned a few pairs (mostly in-ear) I've never seen any that use a separate speaker for the cancellation.  I've opened them up  to repair damaged wires so would have noticed

Comment: @Transistor: Dual voice coil speakers could also be used. I know they exist in larger sizes (including subwoofers), but I don't know if they exist in headset sizes.

Answer (score 2):

This could also be a solution:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUjy6y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The noise cancelling circuit just adds its signal to the driver signal when it is active.

Comment: Possible, but wasteful?

Comment: Yes you lose some power over the 30 ohm resistor but since audio volume works in a logarithmic way you would not notice much volume loss. Also there's not that much power going into a headphone so its not like an mp3 player's battery life is suddenly halved by these resistors. In practice, you will be unable to notice that.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to replicate this behaviour for a guitar pedal that adds extra stuff when turned on, but passes on the input when turned off.

<s>A simple conventional relay can do this, if this is the only thing you want:</s>

A simple circuit with a DPDT can do the job, if this is the only thing you want:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmWGx4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that buffering the signal is a MUST when you use a longer (>= 6m) instrument cable.

**PS:** A similar approach can be found in OD808 pedal.

Comment: Why a Relay, when you can use a DPDT switch?

Comment: DPDT is enough but the active circuit will always be energized and consume power.

Comment: But a relay also wastes power. A 3PDT switch could switch power and 2 audio lines

Comment: @RohatKılıç Yeah, true. 3PDT would do the trick then, switching both signal and power for active circuit. First choice from digikey is [$1.80 for relay](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/kemet/EE2-5NU-L/399-11017-2-ND/4291083) and [$2.57 for switch](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/c-k/7301T1CWZQE/1889-7301T1CWZQE-ND/7897952), so it would be a trade off between the total current consumption from active circuit vs relay consumption and cost of batteries if battery powered.
EDIT: Chris H beat me to it because of adding links.

Comment: The headphone does not have a physical switch like that, rather a button you have to hold. I think it's unlikely a relay or double throw switch is used.

Answer (score 0):

I guess they can use the power switch to bypass the output. Can you see if it still work when you actually press the power switch? Is it even a power switch?[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the toolbar an editable in-line diagram is created. No need for screen-grabs. No CircuitLab subscription required. You can also use the simulator on your circuits.

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry. I see it now. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

This is how typical headphones looks like:

[image]

[Source](https://www.headphone.com)

This is how typical earmuffs looks like:

[image]

[Source](https://www.bunnings.com.au/unisafe-high-performance-ear-muffs_p5823110)

Perhaps, the **passive** functionality of the earmuffs works in a similar manner with a typical headphone.

Maybe, just maybe, the way the headphones are shaped the way they are, is to imitate the **passive** noise canceling feature which earmuffs have.

Remove the padding around the ears and see if your **passive** noise canceling feature disappears, if it does, then we can finally come to terms to why the padding around the ears exists.

Comment: Harry, the earmuffs don't do cancellation. They do attenuation. For noise cancellation we need to actively generate sound pressure waves in anti-phase.

Comment: @Transistor Do you think a human can tell the difference between attenuation and noise cancellation? Hmm, maybe some can. I can't.